# How to exclude code of app.component.html in my other components

Tags: angular, typescript

`app.component.html` which is our default component has a menu added in it, but I don't wish to include it on my other component.

How can I do it?

The problem is when I am loading `newsection.component.html`, it is showing the `app.component.html` on top as shown below:

[image]

How can I restrict it so that it doesn't load above editsection.component.html?

Comment: Do you use router-outlet to display the newsection component?

Comment: in my newsection.html i have added this <app-root *ngIf="showComponent" ><app-root> <router-outlet></router-outlet> and in newsection.ts public showComponent = false; but still it is showing app-root , please advise

Answer (score 11):

You can do a combination of Dhyey and Hamed Baatour's answer.

First of all, create a separate component for your menu (e.g. `menu.component.ts`) and place all of your code in there.

Then modify your `app.component.ts` so that it looks like this:

```
<menu-component *ngIf="showMenu"></menu-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Important:** Now you have to set `showMenu` in your **`app.component.ts`** and *not* in your `newsection.component.ts`.

You can do this by checking the requested URL. Just inject the router in your `app.component.ts` like this:

```
constructor(router:Router) {
router.events.forEach((event) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.showMenu = event.url !== "/newsection";
    }
  });
}
```

This shouldn't show the menu if the route with */newsection* is requested.

Comment: The menu in app-root is opening from appmenu component but the html button is in app.component.html , how do i hide that aswell ?

Comment: If the HTML button is in app.component.html you can use the same ngIf statement as in my example.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, you should understand the nature of Angular as it is a single page application which means a single HTML page is loaded and you can inject other code to it by using the router. But, as a workaround, you can use an `*ngIf` directive to show and hide your app component depending on where the user navigated in the app just like this:

```
if (this.router.url === '/login') {
this.showComponent = false
}
```

and in your template you do the following:

```
<app-root *ngIf="showComponent" ><app-root>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### Edit

`app-root` is the selector of a new component that you create to move your app component HTML and logic into it. In your `app.component.html` template just include the HTML I provided in your `app.component.ts` inject the router and create the variable called `showComponent` and then in your `ngOnInit` or in your constructor add the if statement above to show or hide the `app-root` component depending on the router condition provided.

Comment: in my newsection.html i have added this `<app-root *ngIf="showComponent" ><app-root>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and in newsection.ts `public showComponent = false;`  but still it is showing app-root , please  advise

Comment: @user2828442 no that's wrong! I edited my answer to better explain to you what you should do in depth. hope it's more clear now and if you still didn't understand something just tell me ;)

Comment: The menu in app-root is opening from appmenu component but the html button is in app.component.html , how do i hide that aswell ?

Comment: you can move the button to the `app-root` component or you can use the same technique above using `*ngIf` directive in the component template.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show menu only in few components then make a new component for menu, remove the html for menu from `app.component.html` and include the newly built `menu` component in the files that you want like below:

```
<div id="some-other-component">
    <menu-comp></menu-comp>
    // other html below
</div>
```

Comment: i have made a separate component for menu which i included in `app.component.html` as i need it there but i dont want it to load on my other components, hope you get it

Comment: are you using routing ? if yes does `app.component.html` include `<router-outlet>` ?

Answer (score 0):

A little example that I use. Variable 'title' receive the component location/path. Then in component I check:

In **app.component.ts**

```
isMaps(path) {
    var title = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path());
    title = title.slice(1);
    if (path == title) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**in app.component.html**

```
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div *ngIf="isMaps('maps')">
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
```

If compenent name/path is **maps**, method will return '**false**' then not show foot in **map.component.ts**